# Crystal Report ExportFormatType.EditableRTF

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using VS2010 and CR 11 version: 11.5.12.1838 (i.e. SP6).

I want to export a report to EditableRTF format programmatically.
But i can not find "EditableRTF" in the "ExportFormatType".
"EditableRTF" only can selected from Crystal Report Viewer's export button.

In the BusinessObject website, "EditableRTF" is available for CR11.
http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/crystalreports_dotnet_sdk/crystalreports_net_doc/doc/crsdk_net_doc/html/crlrfexportformattypeenumerationtopic.htm